# Ошибка: не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::ofstream"

Tags: c++

Привет. У меня появилась проблема. 
 Ошибка 1:

> error C2678: бинарный "!=": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::ofstream" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Вот скриншот:
http://content-30.foto.my.mail.ru/mail/sbogdanov2/gamecenter/h-1.jpg
Вот сам код:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

using namespace std;
ofstream ofile; 
char dlldir[320];

bool bCompare(const BYTE* pData, const BYTE* bMask, const char* szMask)
 {
 for(;*szMask;++szMask,++pData,++bMask)
 if(*szMask=='x' && *pData!=*bMask) return 0;
 return (*szMask) == NULL;
 }
 DWORD FindPattern(DWORD dwAddress,DWORD dwLen,BYTE *bMask,char * szMask)
 {
 for(DWORD i=0; i<dwLen; i++)
 if (bCompare((BYTE*)(dwAddress+i),bMask,szMask)) return (DWORD)(dwAddress+i);
 return 0;
 }
void __cdecl add_log (const char *fmt, ...)
 {
 if(ofile != NULL)
 {
 if(!fmt)
 { 
     return;
 }
 va_list va_alist;
 char logbuf[256] = {0};
 va_start (va_alist, fmt);
 _vsnprintf (logbuf+strlen(logbuf), sizeof(logbuf) - strlen(logbuf), fmt, va_alist);
 va_end (va_alist);
 ofile << logbuf << endl;
 }
 }
 char *GetDirectoryFile(char *filename)
 {
 static char path[320];
 strcpy(path, dlldir);
 strcat(path, filename);
 return path;
 }
```

Comment: проверьте типы аргументов в этом вырожении

Comment: А для ostream определён оператор `!=` или `==`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ofstream` нельзя сравнивать с `NULL`, не делайте так.

Вызывайте например `ofile.good()`.